# IBM Watson Questions with Classifier- loads application but I can't see the code

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have worked through the steps on this link successfully and I can see the test application running. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/questions-with-classifier-ega 
Test app electricityadvisor.mybluemix.net

However, when I set up the GIT repo and then start to edit the code, I only see the JAVA HELLO World code. I followed the instructions to the letter and I've gone through the process over 10 times.

Comment: Hey Jonh, open an issue in the repository and explain the problem there

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the vanilla application that you created in stage 1. What you are not seeing is the application that you deployed under the section "Manually creating Bluemix services and deploying to Bluemix".

There are a number of things that could have gone awry.

1. Did you successfully cf push your modified application? If not then you need to work out why?
2. Against which url did you run cf api. If you followed the documentation

   cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net

then you will have bound the the US datacenter, and your application will be there. This may not be the same data center that you are expecting.

3. Check that the application name you specify in manifest.yml matches the application name that you specified in stage1

Comment: Hi and thank you for your comments. I successfully loaded the war file and  could see the app running from the URL. I think I should see the US data center as I followed cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net. I did not see a command to alter the application name in the manifest.yml file, change the characters &#58 to :  I also pushed the test file lauren.war to Bluemix and it runs but I can't see the code. Any pointers please?